i am unable to drop any standard or Custom LWC element from the elements panel to the canvas
I’ve just started learning Lightning Web Components (LWC) and was following a YouTube tutorial. In the tutorial, they’re able to drag a custom LWC component to the Lightning App Builder canvas, but I can’t seem to do it in my org.
What I’ve Tried:
Verified the .js-meta.xml file configuration:
xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="MyComponent">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Deployed the component to my org and confirmed it’s there.
Cleared my browser cache and tried in incognito mode.
Issue: The component still appears in the Lightning App Builder, and I’m unable to drag any custom component and standard component either.
Any advice on what could be wrong or steps to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Hey thanks for your question. Does your org have Setup > Session Settings > "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" enabled? Typically I leave this setting unchecked when developing. I also noticed your metadata is using the full qualified name (fqn) attribute. I haven't had a use case for that attribute before but wanted to verify if there was a need for this on your side.

I noticed you're missing a masterLabel tag, not sure if that would cause the component to not be available. Something like this:
<masterLabel>MyComponent</masterLabel>

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-app-builder.html
Although I see you have fqn and this masterLabel is not even used in this example in Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component.
I would just logout of the org, clear cache again and try again.
